# Is IPV6 only subnet possible with GCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

Hi AWS has support for ipv6 only subnets as described below

```
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/introducing-ipv6-only-subnets-and-ec2-instances/
```

but GCP supports only two stacks IPV4 only and dual stack as described here

```
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#subnet-types
```

IS there a way to create IPV6 only subnets in GCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, IPv6 addresses on a VM interface can only be configured on an interface that is connected to a [dual stack subnet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address#console:%7E:text=To%20configure%20IPv6%20addresses%20on%20a%20VM%20interface%2C%20the%20interface%20must%20be%20connected%20to%20a%20dual%20stack%20subnet.).

[Dual Stack Subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#subnet-types:%7E:text=IPv4%20and%20IPv6%20(dual%2Dstack)%20subnets%2C%20with%20both%20IPv4%20and%20IPv6%20subnet%20ranges) comes with both IPv4 and IPV6 subnet ranges. Google Cloud does not support IPv6 only interface for now.